# Openvpn connnects but public ip still my own

Tags: windows, openvpn

Hi there superuser people.

I am using a vpn (on the OpenVPN protocol) but the connection seems to be not working. my public ip reported by both (cmd.exe ipconfig) and openvpn is x.x.x.x but when i search for my ip on google, y.y.y.y shows, so there must be something wrong...

I am using latest OpenVPN client on windows 8.1 64-bit

I also tested this on a windows 7 pc on the same network
EDIT: to clarify, x.x.x.x is the VPN public IP, while y.y.y.y is my real IP

Comment: cmd.exe ipconfig doesn't show you your external IP? If you load a 'whatismyip' site and its a different IP address then your HTTP traffic is going down the VPN.

Comment: it is not though. that is the point of my question

Comment: Right well OpenVPN is generally on used to pass traffic for the OpenVPN Server down the VPN connection not all traffic. Can you go to command prompt with the VPN connected and run command route print then paste in to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the OpenVPN client as Administrator so the app has permissions to update the routing table.